# Error while adding ItemsSource to ColumnSeries in wpf chart

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit, toolkit

I have couple checkboxes (where content = name from database). In metchod checkbox_checked im trying to add ColumnSeries to wpf Chart, but still getting error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is xaml code:

```
      <DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="wykres1"  Background="LightSteelBlue">

</DVC:Chart>
```

And code-behind:

```
CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;

            ColumnSeries b = new ColumnSeries();
            b.Title = c.Content.ToString();
            b.ItemsSource = null;
            b.ItemsSource =
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
                    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 12),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("CEO", 25),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Software Engg.", 5),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Team Leader", 6),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Leader", 10),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 4) };
            wykres1.Series.Add(b);

            categoryList.Add(c.Tag.ToString());
```

Anyone can help? :)

Answer (score 1):

Working now. Solution was:
      ColumnSeries b = new ColumnSeries {Title=c.Content.ToString(),IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key"), DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value") };